# iOS: Scrolling TableView leads to NSException without details

Tags: ios, xcode8

I have a tableview and get the error

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

if I start scrolling the table. If I jump to other table position with help of the section indices on the right there is no problem. Only the scrolling causes the crash.

What is really weired is that I do not get any further infos. Non of the threads points to my code and I tried it with XCode 8 and XCode 8.1 beta 2.
Usually XCode tells me what the problem is. Also I made sure that all indices are in its bounds, etc.

Any idea how to debug this?

Comment: set an exception breakpoint in your code.

Comment: arghh... I'm so stupid. Thanks man!